# Function of square roots returns value with 0 imaginary part

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am considering the following function called funAl:

```
1/2 (1 + (Sqrt[3] Sqrt[868 - 1700 xi + 825 xi^2])/Sqrt[4 - 25 xi^2])
```

This function occurs as a boundary in one of my integrals which i am integrating with Vegas numerically. For all considered values of xi funAl should be real and less than 1. But for some values of xi (values which are allowed), i get something like:

```
funAl //. xi -> 0.973991669410735`
```

```
0.942244 + 0. I
```

Vegas stopes integrating because of non-real values, but as you see the imaginary part is just 0. NIntegrate for example works perfectly fine. Any ideas why the funtions funAl containing only square roots gives back such values?

The integral is of the following form:

```
contr42 = 
 Vegas[Sqrt[xi^2*u0Max2^2 - mu^2]*u0Max2*1/(2*(2*Pi)^3)*g*
   J2[xi *u0Max2], {xi, 14/15, 1}, {alpha, funAl, 
   1}, {eta, 0, 1}, {rho, 0, 1}, {beta, 0, 1}, MaxPoints -> 10^6]
```

So values of xi are inserted into funAl and return the kind of numbers given above and due to the imaginary part i get an error.

Comment: Add `//Chop`   should be OK

Comment: Both square roots are imaginary at that value of `xi`. The imaginary parts just happen to cancel each other out. But they're there in the intermediate calculations, which means that the expression is type-casted into `Complex`, thus the (float-vanishing) imaginary part. You should use  `Chop` to remove this small number (or, say, `Limit` instead of `ReplaceRepeated`; and, FWIW, you should probably using `ReplaceAll` in the first place anyway).

Comment: both Chop and Limit work for the example above, but the actual problem is the integration error in the integral exression which i added to my question. How can i use Chop or Limit there to get rid of the imaginary part?

Comment: If you are integrating numerically use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision, i.e., specify a `WorkingPrecision`. We cannot verify that it will work since you have not provided a definition for `Vegas`, `J2`, ...

Comment: Does it work if you merge the roots, as in `funAl = 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3 (868 - 1700 xi + 825 xi^2)/(4 - 25 xi^2)])`?

Comment: @Roman Thanks, merging the roots was indeed the solution to the problem.  I will keep it in mind to provide all definitions for the next time ;)